# Как можно считать курсор из функции в рамках другой функции postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть функции, которые возвращают до 5 курсоров, для примера часть кода из одной из них:

```
OPEN ref1 FOR
    SELECT * FROM ResultsList654;
RETURN NEXT ref1;
```

Есть ли способ считать этот курсор внутри другой функции, например я пробую это сделать так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ShowMessage(_mess character varying) RETURNS VOID AS
$_$
BEGIN
    select  spGetFilesList (_useruid := '407a80f3-04af-4b3d-aba3-f4f8a48611b2', parentdocuid :=  '015df005-2acc-4a26-bef9-7b0c126d14c8');
    FETCH ALL ref1;
    FETCH ALL ref2;
    CLOSE ref1;
    CLOSE ref2;
RETURN;
END;
$_$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

На что postgreSQL ругается:

```
ERROR:  expected FROM or IN at or near "ref1"
LINE 5:  FETCH ALL ref1;
```

Но всё отлично работает в рамках транзакции следующим образом:

```
BEGIN;
select  spGetFilesList (_useruid := '407a80f3-04af-4b3d-aba3-f4f8a48611b2', parentdocuid :=  '015df005-2acc-4a26-bef9-7b0c126d14c8');
FETCH ALL ref1;
FETCH ALL ref2;
CLOSE ref1;
CLOSE ref2;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Я знаю, что курсоры можно использовать только в рамках транзакции, но разве функция не выполняется в транзакции? Почему я не могу считать курсор из другой функции в текущей?

Answer (score 0):

Оставлю это здесь, возможно кому-то это понадобиться, кстати в сети не нашёл ничего подобного, понимаю, что практичность у данной функции около нулевая, но мне например нужно было проверить скорость отработки нескольких функций, некоторые из них возвращали курсор, чем добавили мне головной боли...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ShowMessage(_mess character varying) RETURNS VOID AS
$_$
DECLARE  
    ref1 refcursor;
    mviews RECORD;
    mviews1 RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR mviews IN select * from spGetRouteData ('407a80f3-04af-4b3d-aba3-f4f8a48611b2',  '015df005-2acc-4a26-bef9-7b0c126d14c8',  false, null, null, 2)
    LOOP
        ref1 = mviews.spGetRouteData;
        loop
            FETCH ref1 into mviews1;
            if not found then
                exit;
            end if;
        end loop;
        CLOSE ref1;
    END LOOP;
END;
$_$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select ShowMessage('spGetRouteData');
```

Замените spGetRouteData на вызов своей функции.