# Как считать курсор из команды PERFORM в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Есть процедура:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ShowMessage(_mess character varying) RETURNS VOID AS
$_$
BEGIN
    PERFORM spGetFilesList (_useruid := '407a80f3-04af-4b3d-aba3-f4f8a48611b2', parentdocuid :=  '015df005-2acc-4a26-bef9-7b0c126d14c8');
    --FETCH ALL ref1;
    PERFORM    spGetFilesList (_useruid := '407a80f3-04af-4b3d-aba3-f4f8a48611b2', parentdocuid :=  '015df005-2acc-4a26-bef9-7b0c126d14c8');
RETURN;
END;
$_$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Из скрипта видно, что я вызывают одну и ту же функцию, внутри этой функции возвращается курсор "ref1", но считать через FETCH ALL я его не могу, т.к. выпадает ошибка:

```
ERROR:  expected FROM or IN at or near "ref1"
```

Даже если её объявлю её в блоке DECLARE, ошибка не пропадёт, но если я вызову эту же функцию следующим образом:

```
select ShowMessage('sdfsg');
```

Получу другую ошибку:

```
ERROR:  cursor "ref1" already in use
```

Т.е. курсор существует после вызова, но я не могу до него добраться, как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Если что PERFORM не может возвращать результат, в этом и была моя ошибка. Если хотите получить курсор из функции и работать с ним, то вам сюда: [Как можно считать курсор из функции в рамках другой функции postgreSQL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997096/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-postgresql/997182#997182)